# Extracting multiple IO exceptions into polysemy

Tags: haskell, exception, io-monad, free-monad, haskell-polysemy

Let's say I have some very complex set of computations of the form `computation :: IO a` that I cannot modify, due to it being from some library code or other reasons. Let's also say I want to provide some type-level guarantees that we aren't able to launch nuclear missiles in the midst of using these computations, so we use `polysemy` and wrap all these up into its own DSL `Library`. We can naively interpret this with

```hs
runLibraryIO :: Member (Embed IO) r => Sem (Library ': r) a -> Sem r a
runLibraryIO = interpret $ \case
  Computation -> embed computation
  -- ...
```

This is all well and good, but `computation` can throw exceptions! We quickly throw up some code and are able to lift a **single** type of exception into `polysemy`. We write the helper

```
withIOError :: forall e r a . (Exception e, Members '[Embed IO, Error e] r) => IO a -> Sem r a
withIOError action = do
  res <- embed $ try action
  case res of
       Left e  -> throw @e e
       Right x -> pure x
```

and then our interpreter becomes

```hs
runLibraryIO :: Members '[Embed IO, Error MyException] r => Sem (Library ': r) a -> Sem r a
runLibraryIO = interpret $ withIOError @MyException . \case
  Computation -> computation
  -- ...
```

but we quickly notice this is not extensible. In particular, we are only able to lift a single type of exception, and it's limited to computations in `IO`. We cannot dive arbitrarily deep into a monad that contains exceptions and transfer it out in a nice and pure manner. If for whatever reason we discover a corner case where `computation` may throw `MyException'`, we have no way of inserting support for this and catching it elsewhere in our code!

Is there something I am missing in the library that allows me to do this? Am I stuck with dealing with exceptions in `IO`? Some guidance on where to go forward from here and make this sufficiently polymorphic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you may want to do something with [`intercept`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polysemy-1.2.1.0/docs/Polysemy.html#v:intercept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this with a `lower` interpreter. Thanks @KingoftheHomeless.

```hs
withException :: forall e r a . (E.Exception e, Member IOError r, Member (Error e) r) => Sem r a -> Sem r a
withException action = catchIO @r @e action throw

lowerIOError :: Member (Embed IO) r => (forall x. Sem r x -> IO x) -> Sem (IOError ': r) a -> Sem r a
lowerIOError lower = interpretH $ \case
  ThrowIO e -> embed $ E.throwIO e
  CatchIO m h -> do
    m' <- lowerIOError lower <$> runT m
    h' <- (lowerIOError lower .) <$> bindT h
    s  <- getInitialStateT
    embed $ lower m' `E.catch` \e -> lower (h' (e <$ s))
```

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/incertia/ef626297ae541f71c1caf9350fb7e09f) for it in action.